# $L^\infty$ bound on solution of $u_t - \Delta u + cu = f$ and dependence on $c > 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Let $u$ be the weak solution to 
$$u_t - \Delta u + cu = f$$
$$u(0) = 0$$
with zero Neumann data, on a bounded domain and time interval $[0,T]$. Here $c > 0$.

If $f$ is in $L^\infty$ in time and space, what kind of dependence can I get on the $L^\infty$ norm of $u$ on the constant $c$? Can I obtain something like 
$$\lVert u(t) \rVert_\infty \leq  Me^{-ct}\lVert f \rVert_\infty?$$
($M$ independent of $c$)
Or something else giving me decay.

I'm looking for a sharp estimate giving me decay wrt the constant $c$. Basically I would like the RHS of the above inequality to tend to zero as $c \to \infty$.

Comment: If $u$ is a solution of your equation, then
$$
                (e^{-ct}u)_{t}+\Delta(e^{-ct}u) = e^{-ct}f,
$$
and $e^{-ct}u$ satisfies the same Neumann conditions. Have you tried looking at that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that you can obtain the decay estimate that you want. But you can use this way to obtain one estimate of $\|u\|$. Multiplying both sides by $u$ and then integrating, one has
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\|u\|^2+\|\nabla u\|^2+c\|u\|^2=(f,u). $$
By the Poincaré's inequality, $\|\nabla u\|^2\ge \lambda_1\|u\|^2$, where $\lambda_1$ is the first positive eigenvalue of $\Delta$, and by the inequality $2ab\le\frac{1}{\varepsilon}a^2+\varepsilon b^2$, one has
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\|u\|^2+\lambda_1\|u\|^2+c\|u\|^2\le\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\|f\|^2+\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon \|u\|^2. $$
Letting $\frac12\varepsilon=\lambda_1$ in the above inequality gives
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\|u\|^2+c\|u\|^2\le\frac{1}{4\lambda_1}\|f\|^2 $$
which is equivalent to
$$ (e^{ct}\|u\|^2)'\le\frac{1}{4\lambda_1}e^{ct}\|f\|^2. $$
Integrating both sides from 0 to t gives
$$ e^{ct}\|u(t)\|^2\le\frac{1}{4\lambda_1}\int_0^te^{cs}\|f(s)\|^2ds\le\frac{\|f\|^2_\infty}{4\lambda_1c}(e^{ct}-1). $$
Thus one has the following estimate
$$ \|u(t)\|^2\le\frac{\|f\|^2_\infty}{4\lambda_1c}(1-e^{-ct}). $$
So
$$ \|u(t)\|^2\le\frac{\|f\|^2_\infty}{4\lambda_1c} $$
which gives
$$ \lim_{c\to\infty}\|u(t)\|=0. $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping to get an L^\infty bound though.